# Create a thick arrow using only HTML/CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way to create 4 thick arrows pointing up, down, left and right using only html and css?  It's very easy to create the stem of the arrow using s and borders...  It's the diagonal lines of the head of the arrow that I don't know how to do.

I need this to work in IE7+ and all modern browsers.  I use jQuery and am happy to depend on it.  This has to be intimately integrated with other html elements, so I don't want to use something like Raphael to draw it.  Images are problematic because they're difficult to zoom in on smoothly.

I tried the unicode characters for arrows (html entities ⇦, ⇧, ⇨ and ⇩).  This would've been a solution, but they render so very differently in every browser.  Other issues with this include not being able to at least make the inside of the arrows opaque.

Ideally I can fill in the arrows with a gradient.

Comment: Build using css only ;) http://jsfiddle.net/xJrpq/

Comment: @Clyde: You should post that as an answer. Your example may not zoom well, though (because you used pixel units).

Comment: @Clyde, WOW!  I don't understand how that CSS works!?

Comment: Border corners are [mitred](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitre_joint).

Comment: @T.J : what if the unit used was `em`
Also added my comment to an answer that I posted

Comment: This is a great source to check more common used special characters: http://danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=dingb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can still use `⇦` ,i.e the one that you specified in your question.

If you want them to appear bigger, change the font-size using css.

http://jsfiddle.net/yd9gf/

Also
Build using css only ;) http://jsfiddle.net/xJrpq

And here is the code for the css version

**HTML**

```
<div class="b"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.b {
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-left: 60px solid black;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle can move, disappear, etc.; always include the actual code *in* your answer; the fiddle can be a nice adjunct. Clever approach, using the mitring of border corners, I don't know how well it would work with non-pixel units but hey, you never know.

Comment: I was unaware of your 2nd technique, can I fill an arrow like this with gradients?  Can I have borders?  I guess I can by having a slightly bigger arrow underneath...

Comment: Wrapping them in `h1` tags is really, really bad for semantics.

Comment: Even though I didn't end up using this solution, your trick was great and I've put that in my brain storage... so giving you credit for the answer

Answer (score 4):

Did you try these arrows ?

```
↑↓←→↔↕
```

Unicode : 2190 -> 2195

Comment: @all: FWIW: Those arrows look very nearly the same for me on: IE6 (on Windows 2000); IE7 (Windows XP); IE8 (Windows 7); Safari 5 (Windows 7); and Chrome 10, Firefox 3.6, and Opera 11 on both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. The arrows in the OP's question render as empty boxes (missing chars) on IE6/Win2k and IE7/WinXP. They render as unfilled arrows on all the others, though they look just *terrible* in Safari/Win7. So Réjôme's are more consistent and they're filled as requested (though not with a gradient).

Comment: I wanted thick arrows, unfilled is ok, but the inside at least needs to be opaque.

Answer (score 3):

### Short and simple

Use HTML codes

→ ( `&#8594;`  or `&#x2192;`) 
← ( `&#8592;` or `&#x2190;` ) 
↑   ( `&#8593;` or `&#x2191;` ) 
↓   ( `&#8595;` or `&#x2193;` )

**Example:** a→b→c 
code of the above example is `a&#8594;b&#8594;c`

if you want more codes like this then refer : http://character-code.com/arrows-html-codes.php

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go for `svg` in this case and to cover your requirements of IE 7 I would use `vml` as a fall-back. There are conversion tools for `svg` to `vml`. Also both work similar to images but don't look bad when using zoom as they are vector graphics.

Have a look here if this path appeals to you:
http://vectorconverter.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Can I easily have drop shadows with svg/vml?  That and easy borders are the only problems with the mitred corner example Clyde gave.

Answer (score 1):

Use an image possibly consisting of sprites.

By the time the other solutions files are downloaded,  you'll probably be at the same size or greater than an optimised image.  In any case images are totally reliable and work on all browsers;  an esoteric solution,  whilst fun to create,  may be a support nightmare (nobody ever complains on the internet so you won't know when its broken).

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered pretty well, but what about simply codes like: ▼ (that's &#9660;)

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25bc/index.htm

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b2/index.htm

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25ba/index.htm

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25c4/index.htm

Comment: I was looking for an arrow instead of a triangle... I ended up using the mitred border corners, not ideal (shadows don't work right, gradients and different borders don't work either) but it got the job done...

Answer (score 0):

You could try too get two boxes ratate them to diaomnds, and create a rectangle behind them set borders too 1px

Comment: Can I rotate the boxes easily to be compatible with at least IE8?

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of options.

- Option 1: Webdings font : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings
- Option 2: Custom downloadable CSS font
- Option 3: Over-sized/High-res image scaled down
- Option 4: SVG inline or as image
- Option 5: Any of the above rotated using CSS transforms

Option 2 is probably the most reliable. Option 5 is support in IE7 using MS vendor extensions like filters and writing-mode.

```
.rotated {
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-rotation-point: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-webkit-rotation-point: 0 0;
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
* html writing-mode: tb-lr;
}
```

Comment: Can I use css transforms with IE8?

Comment: equivalents yes, see my edit. I've used it before see http://www.inwardpath.com.au/

Comment: the code sample above works with 90deg rotations. For 45deg there is an MS filter (it's hard to use though).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to do like this:

```
span { font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: -5px}

<span>&#61;&#62;</span>
```

looks like this: =>

(looks better when style gets applied, which it doesn't seem to do here)

Comment: with this solution you can do only 2 arrows: pointing left and right. What happens to the others: pointing up and down?

Comment: Yes, I thought of that also .. and still simple answer, if one wants to stay with "chars" and not do font download or images, you use Writing-Mode/Filter/Rotate/Transform .. keeps things fast render and maintainable (and this solution only needed on older browsers where the Unicode version does not work)